# Collecting per-day results for queries over date-partitioned tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have some tables with names such as `counts_20171220` in BigQuery with rows in this format (there is only one row per `contentId` per date):

```
| contentId | views |
+-----------+-------+
| cb32edc0  | 728324|
| 52cbb1ff  | 643220|
...
```

I want to generate a list of the view count for a given `contentId` for a given time range, without gaps, e.g:

```
|       date |  views |
+------------+--------+
| 2017-12-01 |   NULL | -- or 0
| 2017-12-02 |   NULL | -- or 0
| 2017-12-03 | 728314 |
| 2017-12-04 | 328774 |
| 2017-12-05 |  28242 |
...
| 2017-12-20 |   NULL | -- or 0
```

In order to do this, I guess I need to use `*` and `_table_suffix`, but I'm not able to figure out how to include the dates for which there is no entry for that `contentId`. The closest I have got is this query:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  _table_suffix AS date,
  ARRAY_AGG(views) AS views
FROM
  `test.counts_*`
WHERE
  _table_suffix BETWEEN '20171201' AND '20171220'
  AND contentId = 'cb32edc0'
GROUP BY
  _table_suffix,
  contentId
ORDER BY
  date
```

The problem with this query is

1. it does not include rows for all dates, only for dates whose table had an entry for `contentId` 'cb32edc0'
2. due to the way it's structured I need to use a (useless here) aggregate function to extract `views`

How should I structure a query like this? I'd be happy to get both specific help for this query and general pointers on how to achieve things like this where one queries over date-partitioned tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, assuming that there is at least one row for each date:

```
SELECT
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX) AS date,
  IFNULL(MAX(IF(contentId = 'cb32edc0', views, NULL)), 0) AS views
FROM `test_counts_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20171201' AND '20171220'
GROUP BY date;
```

Instead of explicitly filtering the rows that don't match the desired `contentId`, it uses a condition with an aggregate function to exclude them from the result. If there are no rows in the group with the desired `contentId`, the `IFNULL` ensures that the expression returns `0` rather than `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks! That's actually quite elegant!